How are boot nodes fetched for system chains / parathreads?
The Polkadot JS API api.rpc.syncstate.genSyncSpec, that fetches boot nodes for the relay chains, is not an available function for system chains.
What is the process of gathering boot nodes for system / parachains, e.g. for Smoldot Chain Specs?
Here is an example of boot nodes for Polkadot Asset Hub: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-connect/blob/main/packages/connect-known-chains/specs/polkadot_asset_hub.json.
Knowing this process would be useful for future system and parathreads who wish to create their own records.
